# Pyinstaller and displaying korean characters

Tags: python, windows, utf-8, pyinstaller

I'm a beginner and I created a small flash card script to help me study korean. the script uses a two column spreadsheet with A being the Keys, and B being the definition. I then used pyinstaller --onefile to change it into a one-ish file(still needs the spreadsheet) .exe to run.

The question is when it displays the Korean characters such as 자다 in the text window it displays two [?][?] boxes, how do i get it to display the true characters?

I was able to use the script, and view all korean characters while i was coding it in pycharm

Thanks!

Comment: the text window is a normal windows console, i think...

Comment: Python 3.6+ uses the console's wide-character (Unicode) API, but the console won't necessarily be able to render the text properly since it uses old GDI APIs that don't support automatic font fallback. This is the case if you can copy and paste the box glyphs into notepad and it renders properly as Korean text. You may be able to select a font in the console that supports Korean.

Comment: I just installed the Korean language pack in Windows 10, and this added BatangChe, DotumChe, GulimChe, and GungsuhChe to the console font list. It's not as simple as this prior to Windows 10.

Comment: Hey Thanks! that worked i think i already had the Korean pack installed so i didnt see anything different with the selectable default fonts so i didnt know they were different. i was just using lucida console, but those definitely allow me to view korean characters